# Error while running react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I have followed the instruction that are on this link. But app is not starting on emulator [image]

1. I then follow the instructions on  Delete the node_modules folder -
   rm -rf node_modules && npm install
2. Reset packager cache - rm -fr
       $TMPDIR/react-* or node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh
       --reset-cache
3. Clear watchman watches - watchman watch-del-all Recreate the project
   from scratch

and also create whole new project again to but every time this error pops-up

I have

- npm 4.6.1
- node v8.11.4
- jdk version 8

> ```
> {
>   "name": "p3",
>   "version": "0.0.1",
>   "private": true,
>   "scripts": {
>     "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
>     "test": "jest"
>   },
>   "dependencies": {
>     "react": "16.4.1",
>     "react-native": "0.56.0"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
>     "babel-preset-react-native": "5",
>     "jest": "23.5.0",
>     "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
>   },
>   "jest": {
>     "preset": "react-native"
>   }
> }
> ```

Any help please.

Comment: React and React-Native versions?

Comment: @HedeH  edited my post with version specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been observed that, latest react native version is having a bug in dependencies. I have found it working by modifying the package.json file. Please upadate your package.json file by adding below code:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
 },
```

and then use below commands:

```
npm update
npm cache clean --force
cd android
gradlew clean
cd..
react-native run-android
```

Comment: my react-native version is different so, I will follow your instruction shortly. Currently I am updating my android studio so will not able to run emulator. Will tell you results when completed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using the `react-native 0.56.0` version,

**Try this configuration in `package.json`:**

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
  "react": "^16.4.2",
  "react-native": "^0.56.0",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
  "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
  "babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.0",
  ...
},
```

**If that doesn't work, also try running this script:**

Add a script to the `scripts` section in the `package.json` file under the root project dir and call it `build:android`: (The name doesn't matter)

```
{
  ... 
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build:android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Run it from the terminal like this:

```
npm run build:android
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thankyou I will try your solution shortly. Currently Update is running. Will inform you results after following your instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the project using stable versions, do `react-native init <Project Name> --version="0.55.2"`. After this try `react-native run-android`.