# Error when i install react-native and first run

Tags: android, react-native

I am install react-native and first run in genymotion. I have a trouble.

[image: ScreenShot error]

Comment: Did you try my answer @abdul-rahmat?

Comment: Duplicate of this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52180666/error-while-running-react-native-run-android Please find solution at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52180666/error-while-running-react-native-run-android/52181138#52181138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first delete node_modules folder  and in package.json
change react-native version "react-native": "0.55.2", and
  babel "babel-preset-react-native": "4", after that run yarn install or
npm install and run its work fine for me.

Comment: after npm install, I have this error : Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

Answer (score 1):

Incompatible versioning problem in React Native is the reason for this. Try following.

```
npm remove --save react-native
npm i --save react-native@0.55.4
npm remove babel-preset-react-native
npm i --save babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

Let me know if you get any issues after trying this.

Comment: yes, I'did but 'react-native run-android' command unrecognized

Comment: @AbdulRahmat - Make sure you are inside the your react native project. Delete package-lock.json file and run npm install. Then try react-native run-android. Also don't forget to open the android emulator when you are running this command.

Comment: @AbdulRahmat - If this works , please comment and make my answer as the correct answer , because I'm the one who gave you the answer first :)